# How to solve the infinite digset loop error for directive consists of multiple directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting infinite digest looping error for the directive which consists of sub-directives.How to solve this error as I consists of multiple directives.

Here is my directive code:

```
    app.directive('autoCompDrctve', function ($timeout) {
    return {
    scope: {
        selectedIndex: '=',
        suggestions: '=',
        dropdownid: '@',
        select: '&'
    },

    link: function (scope, element) {

        scope.selectedIndex = 0;

        var elem = angular.element(document.getElementById('autotext'));
        var list = 
      angular.element(document.getElementById(scope.dropdownid));

        list.css('display', 'none');

        elem.bind('focus', function () {
            scope.selectedIndex = 0;
            scope.$apply();
            list.css('display', 'block');
        });

        elem.bind('blur', function () {
            $timeout(
              function () {
                  list.css('display', 'none');
              }, 100
            )
        });

        elem.bind("keydown", function (event) {


            if (list.css('display') === 'none') {
                list.css('display', 'block');
            }

            if (event.keyCode === 40) { //down key, increment selectedIndex
                event.preventDefault();
                if (scope.selectedIndex + 1 === scope.suggestions.length) {
                    scope.selectedIndex = 0;
                } else {
                    scope.selectedIndex++;
                }
                scope.$apply();
            } else if (event.keyCode === 38) { //up key, decrement 
        selectedIndex
                event.preventDefault();

                if (scope.selectedIndex === 0) {
                    scope.selectedIndex = scope.suggestions.length - 1;
                } else {
                    scope.selectedIndex--;
                }
                scope.$apply();

            } else if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.keyCode === 9) { 
        //enter pressed or tab

                elem.val(scope.suggestions[scope.selectedIndex].Name);
                list.css('display', 'none');
                scope.hmSelect(scope.suggestions[scope.selectedIndex]);
                scope.$apply();

            } else if (event.keyCode === 27) {
                list.css('display', 'none');
            }
        })

    }
};
  }).directive('hoverClass', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {

        element.on('mouseenter', function () {




angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName(attr.hoverClass)).removeClass(attr.hoverClass);
            element.addClass(attr.hoverClass);
        });

        element.on('mouseleave', function () {
            element.removeClass(attr.hoverClass);
        });

    }
};
})

  .directive('SelectDown', function () {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        hmSelectDown: '&'
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
        var list = 
angular.element(document.getElementById(scope.hmDropdownid));
        elem.bind('click', function () {
            scope.hmSelectDown();
            list.css('display', 'none');
        });
    }
};
})

.filter('highlight', function ($sce) {
return function (text, phrase) {
    if (phrase)
        text = text.replace(new RegExp('(' + phrase + ')', 'gi'), '<span 
class="highlighted">$1</span>');
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
 }
});
```

The error which is shown below in image:

[image]

Comment: You dont need $scope.apply in functions that attached to events like click, focus, keydown.

Comment: @ Leguest but the page is not loading when I removed the $scope.apply,Iam unable to understand.

Comment: Can you provide JSFiddle? Why its not loading? I dont see any async events that need $apply